# How do I approach analyzing the pass rate for a course last year compared to previous years?

Tags: time-series, inference, multilevel-analysis

I have the final marks since 2012 for a course taught over 1 year.  This past year, 2017, a new curriculum was introduced for this course.  Special tutors were also hired to help students with the new curriculum as it was deemed more difficult than the old curriculum.  The school would now like to know, how did 2017 compare with previous years?

Format of data:

```
| Year | StudentID | School  | FinalMark |
|------|-----------|---------|-----------|
| 2016 |       123 | School1 |        67 |
| 2015 |       345 | School2 |        88 |
| 2014 |       213 | School3 |        76 |
```

I have taken the following approach but am wondering if there is a better way:

- I calculate the percentage of students that passed the course (mark of 60 or greater) for each year.
- Since 2016 was a dire year, I exclude it from the dataset.
- I then compare the pass rate for 2017 with the average of 2012 to 2015.

```
| Year | Pass Rate |
|------|-----------|
| 2012 | 55.30%    |
| 2013 | 54.20%    |
| 2014 | 63.00%    |
| 2015 | 64.20%    |
| 2016 | 45.30%    |
| 2017 | 52.40%    |
```

- If this approach makes sense, what more can I say about 2017 vs the average of 2012 - 2015?

As I have the final mark for each student in each year, I could compare their averages rather than calculating the pass rate.  My concern is that the course is given by different teachers and their is a subjective component to the grading.  On the other hand, to pass the class, the student has to have acquired certain skills, so there is less subjectivity involved.

Also note that the dataset is small, ~120 records per year over 15 schools.  Many schools have less than 10 students for this course.